# What script font is is used for the Villa Rheinblick logo?

Tags: fonts, typography, font-identification

a friend needs a relaunch of his website, gave me all the data he has including a 2kb .gif of the logo which is just a pain in the eye!
He doesn't know which font this is, directed me to the whattjhefont-page… smh

I thought it could be the Snell Roundhead by Adobe, but i'm not sure.

Anyone there who recognize it?
Thanks!

[image: Logo]

Comment: I think you're right, I think the font above is Snell Roundhand Bold Script Font. You can view this at [https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/linotype/snell-roundhand-script/](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/linotype/snell-roundhand-script/)

Comment: Might as well make that an answer @AndrewH :)

Comment: It is the font! Andrew make an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're right, I think the font above is Snell Roundhand Bold Script Font. You can view this at https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/linotype/snell-roundhand-script/

Comment: there you go :) Thank you for the link! i checked it and it is exactly the right font!